# Pasting image with no black background added with python

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, paste

I am trying to take a screenshot and paste the cursor over it, but when I run my program the result is that the cursor was pasted with large black background, does anyone know how i could get the black background disappear?

This is my code:

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open("screenShot.png")
mouse = Image.open(r"C:\Windows\Cursors\aero_arrow.cur")
im.paste(mouse, (40,40)) #Drawing the cursor
im.save("newImage.png")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify a mask, so the black part isn't rendered.
See the [docs](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm#tag-Image.Image.paste):

> im.paste(image, box, mask)
>
> Same as above, but updates only the regions indicated by the mask. You
>   can use either “1”, “L” or “RGBA” images (in the latter case, the
>   alpha band is used as mask). Where the mask is 255, the given image is
>   copied as is. Where the mask is 0, the current value is preserved.
>   Intermediate values can be used for transparency effects.
>
> **Note that if you paste an “RGBA” image, the alpha band is ignored. You
>   can work around this by using the same image as both source image and
>   mask.**

That last part should be your situation.

So in your case you could use `im.paste(mouse, (40,40), mouse)` given that that image already has an alpha channel

Edit:

Apparently the problem has to do with the format `.cur`. If you enter `mouse.getbands()` it will return `(R, G, B)`, hence the `ValueError`.
You could convert the `.cur` file to a `.png` with an alpha channel, however I have also gotten the following to work:

```
mouse_mask = mouse.convert("L")
im.paste(mouse, (40,40), mouse_mask)
```

Comment: I tried this before but got error message of `ValueError: bad transparency mask`

Comment: There is another problem, when i use this mask, the black line border of the mouse disappears too and I get only white mouse,  any ideas why?

Comment: @EyalS Sorry, but I think this has to do with how PIL handles these images, but I don't know. You could still try saving the cursor as a PNG the way you want it with all the transparent/black pixels you want. Since `.cur` is a Windows specific file format there isn't really that much open-source support.